# Facebook Login sometimes does not return email, even if authorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, facebook-login, omniauth

I have seen this problem before but never found a solution.
I am using the Rails Omniauth with Facebook.
I want to get name and email, so I set it up:

```
config.omniauth :facebook, "xxx", "xxx", callback_url: "xxx", info_fields: 'email, first_name, last_name'
```

I have a couple of Facebook accounts and with all it works just fine. I get all values returned and the user is stored in the DB.

But my client tries to login with Facebook and the Hash FOR SOME USERS does not contain the email, for others it does.

I have already checked:

- User shares the email in the authorize dialog
- Client has email address set up for his Facebook account (to make sure he is not using only his phone number)

Where else should I check?

Comment: The users email may not be verified. If so Facebook will not return it

Comment: or the user might have created the account with a phone number ?, you don't necessarily need the email. So, do not rely on it.